# way to check spring cloud stream source and sink data content

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Is there any way I can check what data is there in spring cloud dataflow stream source(say some named destination ":mySource") and sink(say "log" as sink)?

```
e.g. dataflow:>stream create --name demo --definition ":mySource>log"
```

Here what is there in mySource and log - how to check?

Is it like I have to check spring cloud dataflow log somewhere to get any clue, if it at all has logs? If so, what is the location of logs for windows environment?

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in the payload content, you can deploy the stream with the DEBUG logs for the Spring Integration package, which will print the header + payload information among many other interesting lifecycle details. The logs will be either the payload consumed or produced depending on the application-type *(i.e., source, processor, or sink)*.

In your case, you can view the payload consumed by the `log-sink` via:

> dataflow:>stream create --name demo --definition ":mySource > log --logging.level.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG"

We have plans to add native provenance/lineage support with the help of Zipkin and Sleuth in the future releases.

Comment: thanks @Sabby. When you say "you can view", you meant in where I will be able to see those logs in windows environment? - in dataflow server log location (say   -   C:\Users\qatester2\AppData\Local\Temp\spring-cloud-dataflow-1581962961514593958\dataSplit-1507877407484\dataSplit.log) or in command prompt itself of dataflow server or somehwere els

Comment: You will be able to see it in the logs of the applications where you included the property override. In the example above, you will see it in the `log-sink` logs. Please note that the "server" and "apps" are entirely different apps (_individual JVMs_); they all live in isolation. More specifically, the "server" doesn't have any state/logs about the apps.